# Pandas .min() method doesn't seem fastest

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I'm trying to take `min`s, `max`s, `mean`s, etc. of columns of my Pandas df (all numeric values of some kind) and it doesn't seem that Pandas methods are fastest.  It seems like if I first hit it with `.values` the runtime of these operations is greatly improved.  Is this desired behavior (meaning is Pandas doing something silly or intended? Perhaps I'm using up extra memory by hitting it with `.values` or I'm making assumptions and/or making it easier in some way that's not a given...).

"Evidence" of the unexpected behavior:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100000000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

start = time.time()
print(df['A'].min())
print(time.time()-start)`

# 0
# 1.35876178741


start = time.time()
df['A'].values.min()
print(time.time()-start)

# 0
# 0.225932121277

start = time.time()
print(np.mean(df['A']))
print(time.time()-start)

# 499.49969672
# 1.58990907669

start = time.time()
print(df['A'].values.mean())
print(time.time()-start)

# 499.49969672
# 0.244406938553
```

Comment: You should not use `time.time()` for profiling. There is module `timeit` for this purpose.

Comment: understood. in the future will use `timeit`, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you just call a column, you are reducing it to a pandas series, which is based on a numpy array but with a lot more wrapped around it. Pandas objects are optimized for spreadsheet or database-type operations like joins, lookups, etc.

When you call `.values` on a column, it makes it a numpy array, which is a dtype optimized for mathematical and vector operations in `C`. Even with the 'unwrapping' to ndarray type, the mathematical operation efficiency beats the series datatype hands-down. [Here is a quick discussion on some of the differences.](https://medium.com/@ericvanrees/pandas-series-objects-and-numpy-arrays-15dfe05919d7)

As a side note, there is a specific module - `timeit` for these type of time comparisons

```
type(df['a'])

pandas.core.series.Series

%timeit df['a'].min()

6.68 ms ± 121 µs per loop

type(df['a'].values)

numpy.ndarray

%timeit df['a'].values.min()

696 µs ± 18 µs per loop
```

Comment: Cool.  Is there a reason that Pandas `.min()` doesn't just default to doing this automatically? Is there some (non-time) cost to this?

Comment: Several reasons that I can think of off the top of my head, the most important being that python doesn't generally change the type of an object unless the user explicitly asks it to, to prevent type confusion. That's why they include the `.values` attribute in case you want to use it, but you might be building additional series operations on top of the `.min()` that don;t work on ndarrays

Comment: This doesn't explain the difference between `df['A'].mean()` vs `df['A'].values.mean()` though (the first one is faster on my machine).

Comment: On my machine, I got `1.16 ms ± 43.2 µs per loop` for `column.mean()`, and `901 µs ± 20.3 µs per loop` for `column.values.mean()`. Not a huge difference, but noticeable. (Dataframe built on 1,000,000 rows of random int). If I do a `.mean` operation on the same length series of floats, I get ~8x better run time with `.values()` (`8.73 ms` vs. `1.2 ms`)

Comment: Pandas methods have a lot of overhead.  Some of this is dealing with NaN data, index alignment etc..